# Convert String array to ArrayList

Tags: java

I want to convert `String` array to `ArrayList`. For example String array is like:

```
String[] words = new String[]{"ace","boom","crew","dog","eon"};
```

How to convert this String array to ArrayList?

Comment: +1; it's now the second link on google.

Comment: ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(words));

Comment: You can do it in 3 basic ways. Using Collections.addAll, Arrays.asList and streams in Java 8 - Reference - http://www.codingeek.com/java/how-to-convert-array-to-list-in-java/

Answer (score 339, accepted):

Use this code for that,

```
import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  

public class StringArrayTest {

   public static void main(String[] args) {  
      String[] words = {"ace", "boom", "crew", "dog", "eon"};  

      List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);  

      for (String e : wordList) {  
         System.out.println(e);  
      }  
   }  
}
```

Comment: In summary all you need is the line `List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words); `. Is this correct?

Comment: @Keale If `words` is an array of strings, then, yes.

Comment: Beware: Arrays.asList(...) creates an AbstractList, not a real list. So you can do stuff like wordList.sort((a, b) -> a.length() - b.length()), but you can not do wordList.remove(0), or add to it. This will throw UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: This code creates a List but it is not an ArrayList. So it is an incorrect answer. You cant delete elements from that List -> will throw an exception.

Comment: @Vito I have to agree that this is probably not a solution to a real problem unless someone can tell my why you would want to convert String[] to List and then not update the list.

Comment: @jeff6times7 You can use Collections API on it, lambdas, filter it, display, concatenate, sort, whatever... etc. Loads of things

Comment: @Vito I got confused by the trailing sentence in your comment. If you had not written about changes to the list, then I would have had no need to ask you for clarification. When you said you can't delete from it, I went down the rabbit trail of thinking that you rejected the answer because you can't delete from it. But deleting from it is irrelevant because it's not a correct answer. It's that simple.

Comment: The question was to convert to ArrayList. It does not produce that class type. It produces object that implements List but not ArrayList. The For uses of the former or latter refer to documentation or other forums.

Comment: This answer does not create an "ArrayList" as asked by the OP...

Comment: Why doesn't it throw a compilation error "String[] cannot be converted to String"? Whenever I pass an array as a parameter for `asList()`, it returns a `List` of one element, that array ‍♂️

Answer (score 183):

```
new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( new String[]{"abc", "def"} ) );
```

Comment: i think that this solution is better because `Arrays.asList` return a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList.ArrayList<T>(T[])` so if you try to `add` something you'll get a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`

Comment: If you have limited number of elemenets in the array, it can be written as 
new ArrayList( Arrays.asList("abc", "def"));

Comment: To avoid IDE warnings, `new ArrayList<>(...)` worked for me as opposed to `new ArrayList(...)` (note the `<>`).

Comment: Best answer for me. With `List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);`, doing `wordList instanceof ArrayList<String>` will return false.

Answer (score 55):

Using [Collections#addAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-)

```
String[] words = {"ace","boom","crew","dog","eon"};
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); 
Collections.addAll(arrayList, words);
```

Comment: I like this solution. It is concise and clean.

Comment: Quite why this is not the accepted answer is unknown to me.

Comment: This is the right answer. asList is wrong. use Collection.addAll(arrayList, string array)...

Comment: This is the right solution if you want an mutable list from an array which is likely what we are looking for anyway. In the off chance an immutable list is needed, the above code accomplishes that task.

Answer (score 29):

```
String[] words= new String[]{"ace","boom","crew","dog","eon"};
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
```

Comment: The result here is a `List`, but not an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you are right, this needs to be wrapped so List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));

Answer (score 12):

in most cases the `List<String>` should be enough. No need to create an `ArrayList`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
```

...

```
String[] words={"ace","boom","crew","dog","eon"};
List<String> l = Arrays.<String>asList(words);

// if List<String> isnt specific enough:
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(l);
```